# Comment on the validity of this redux simplify

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have some coding experience with React & Redux one and half year ago. And then I have been using Vue & Vuex in this year. I like the simplicity of the Vuex structure. So when I return to React & Redux. I want to try some way to make Redux code structure become more simplify.

I have try to define the State and Action using a single object(like Vuex). Then use reduxGenerator function to generate 'reducer' and 'action creator'.

But I didn't think deeply about this. I always worried about this method will cause some problems.

I know that Redux splits the 'state', 'reducer', 'action type' and 'action creator' to make the structure clearer. The team can work together to write different part of the entire state. But more often in my team. Everyone is assigned a different module. One developer needs to face all 'state', 'reducer', 'action type' and 'action creator' code in multiple place. And the Developer need to manually write some 'mechanized' code. But why developers still maintain this initial Redux code structure all the time. Is my method causing some serious problems?

Example code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-simplify-v07n9

Redux Object

```js
const lists = {
  naming: "lists",
  initState: [
    {
      id: idGenerator(),
      name: "List 1"
    },
    {
      id: idGenerator(),
      name: "List 2"
    }
  ],
  actions: {
    addList(state) {
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          id: idGenerator(),
          name: "New List"
        }
      ];
    },

    // ....
  }
}

export default reduxGenerator(lists);
```

reduxGenerator

```js
export default ({ naming, initState, actions }) => {
  const redux = {};

  redux.actionCreator = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(actions).map(action => [
      action[0],
      args => ({
        type: `${naming}/${action[0]}`,
        args
      })
    ])
  );

  redux.reducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    console.log(`%c action: ${action.type}`, "color: #00BEBE");

    const actionType = /.+\/.+/.test(action.type)
      ? action.type.split("/")[1]
      : action.type;

    if (Object.keys(actions).includes(actionType)) {
      return actions[actionType](state, action.args);
    }

    console.error(`${action.type} not found!`);
    return state;
  };

  return redux;
}
```

So I hope to discuss the rationality of this. To help me jump out of my personal limitations.

This may not be a general question in stackoverflow. Please forgive me.

Comment: You are correct that this is not a good question for Stack Overflow and will likely be closed because of that. Additionally, code under review must be in the question itself, not only on an external site. If there is too much code, that is an indication that you are asking a question that is too broad in scope. Finally, if you want a review of all aspects of the code, and the code works as is, you might have better luck on [codereview.se], but I implore you to read their help center first *before* asking.

Comment: Very sorry. I can try to put the core code here. But I thought that It's not very easy to read at here, needs to be in an environment.

Comment: Again, the overall question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, code or no code.

Comment: I have put some core code here. But this still can't change this question will not have  a 'correct' answer. Sorry!